CSS issue with animation-back of nth-of-type
I'm trying to target every nth-of-type for returning to the original position sequentially like moving to the right in this way. I'm new to programming.
I tried to assign to each different transform: translateX($) turn to transform: translateX(0) but it doesn't work ofc.


.character-img {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(Jenna/Images/avatar.png);
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 750px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  animation-fill-mode: both;

}

.character-img:hover {
  animation: width ease-in-out 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 750px;
  .characer-item-card:nth-of-type(1) {
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
  }
  .characer-item-card:nth-of-type(2) {
    transform: translateX(120%);
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
  }
  .characer-item-card:nth-of-type(3) {
    transform: translateX(240%);
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
  }
  .characer-item-card:nth-of-type(4) {
    transform: translateX(360%);
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
  }
  .characer-item-card:nth-of-type(5) {
    transform: translateX(480%);
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
  }
  .characer-item-card:nth-of-type(6) {
    transform: translateX(600%);
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
  }
  @keyframes .character-title {
    width: auto;
  }
  @keyframes transform-back {
    from {
      transform: translateX(120%);
    }
    to {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }
  .characer-item-card {
    z-index: none;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
  }
  #preview-card {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes width {
  from {
    width: 25%;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes width-back {
  from {
    width: 100%;
  }
  to {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
<div class="character-img">
  <div class="character-card">
    <div class="character-title">
      <p> <span class="character-name">Jenna</span></p>
      <span class="character-description">Jenna is the main character of the anime. Her name is Jenna.
                        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="cards">
      <img class="characer-item-card" id="card-1" src="Jenna/Images/1.jpg" alt=""> <img class="characer-item-card" id="card-2" src="Jenna/Images/2.jpg" alt=""><img class="characer-item-card" id="card-3" src="Jenna/Images/3.jpg" alt=""><img class="characer-item-card"
        id="card-4" src="Jenna/Images/4.jpg" alt=""><img class="characer-item-card" id="card-5" src="Jenna/Images/5.jpg" alt=""><img class="characer-item-card" id="card-6" src="Jenna/Images/6.jpg" alt=""> <img class="characer-item-card" id="preview-card"
        src="Jenna/Images/preview.png" alt="">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Add the relevant html code too

I'm still not sure I understand the request. Do you want to achieve something like this? With the words appearing one by one from right to left?

You need to use transition: transform, not animation, and if you want the animation to be dynamic, you need to use javascript.
